# Configuring high-availability with snapshots

Tags: high-availability, vmware-vsphere, snapshot

I wanted to know if it is possible to configure HA in VMware vSphere to start virtual servers using snapshots.

For example, if one of my physical server fails, the virtual machine would start on another physical server using a snapshot previously taken.

Comment: This sounds dangerous - if your hardware fails your VM's suddenly revert to an old image? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was asked to check if it was doable but I didn't really think of the consequences it could cause.

Comment: You might use such a feature to restore a VM to a snapshot in case the VM stops responding.  I can imagine times you might want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware Shapshots are ideal for short term operations (backups, patching, testing a hardware change, etc.) but shouldn't be used long-term.  The delta file for the snapshot continues to grow and consume additional disk space.  It's not worth the headache of dealing with a full datastore or trying to delete a huge snapshot down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Dependent on an if, but if you have a SAN or shared storage of any type I would assume and a cluster you can set the VMs to fail over using HA, you wouldn't need a snapshot, it can move the current state to another host.